# How to get JSON request from Google Maps Geocode API

Tags: php, json, google-maps

For some reason the JSON request for Google Maps Goeocode API isn't working.  If you type this url in the address bar:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway+Mountain+View+CA&sensor=false
```

It will return this:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Note that example is taken directly from the Google Developers site: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/.

How can you retrieve the JSON request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't return this to me.

You simply made too many queries.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   geolocation requests per day.(User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.)

Answer (score 0):

It only doesn't work for you since you exceeded the limit of the Google Maps API.

You need to wait some time, get a new IP address or pay money to google.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing for information on the limits, prices, etc.